# Unable to mount ubuntu directory to Linux(SLES 11 SP2)

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs, cifs, suse

Trying to mount **ubuntu directory:**`/home/suvasish/Downloads/SLES11_SP2/` to SLES(11 SP2) server.

**Tried like below:** `NFS mount`

In  Ubuntu side edited the **/etc/exports** like below..

```
/home/suvasish/Downloads/SLES11_SP2/ *(rw,no_subtree_check,all_squash,insecure,async,nohide)
exportfs -ra
```

In SLES side

```
mkdir -p /mnt/sles11_sp2
test11:~ # mount -t nfs x.x.x.x:/home/suvasish/Downloads/SLES11_SP2/ /mnt/sles11_sp2/
```

**and getting this message**
*`mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported`*

also tried the CIFS mount

```
test11:~ # mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/home/suvasish/Downloads/SLES11_SP2/ /mnt/sles11_sp2/
Password: 
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

the above two also results the same.

***Any idea how can i mount my ubuntu drive to the other linux server.***

**--UPDATE--**

***Configure samba share like below..***

`[SLES11_SP2]
    comment = SLES11 DVD's
    browseable = yes
    path = /home/suvasish/Downloads/SLES11_SP2
    available = yes
    guest ok = yes
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    read only = no`

***and tried to mount the share like***

`test11:~ # mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/home/suvasish/Downloads/SLES11_SP2/ -o user=suvasish,password=xxx /mnt/sles11_sp2/`

`test11:~ # mount -t cifs x.x.x.x:/home/suvasish/Downloads/SLES11_SP2/ -o user=suvasish,password=xxx /mnt/sles11_sp2/`

***Getting the above mentioned error.***

Answer (score 1):

For NFS:

- check if NFS server is running (run `showmount -e` on server - You should see list of nfs-exported folders);
- try mounting folders on the server itself via nfs (loopback using `mount -t nfs`);
- check firewalls on both machines;
- check `/proc/filesystems` on client if `nfs` (or `nfs4`) is supported.

There are a few versions of NFS: NFSv2 (rarely seen, historical), NFSv3 (easyest one to configure), NFSv4 (advanced, but more complex to configure properly). Your `/etc/exports` seem to be NFSv3. NFSv3 can work vian TCP and UDP.

For CIFS:

- configure [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) to export this folder first.
- check if folder is exported/accesible with `smbclient -L x.x.x.x -U suvasish` and `smbclient -L x.x.x.x -U suvasish //x.x.x.x/SLES11_SP2`
- try mounting (`//x.x.x.x/SLES11_SP2` , not the full path with `mount.cifs`)

Comment: Configued Samba and tried with cifs with supplying username, password, but result is same.
Please see the UPDATE section of my post and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

**Managed to get it work.**
`CIFS` hides the underlying file system structure. The appropriate command to mount the “SLES11_SP2” share is as follows:

> mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/SLES11_SP2 /mnt/sles11_sp2/